# SAS o VBA excel ordenar datos de izquierda a derecha respetando cabeceros de columnas

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy intentando ordenar datos como de forma descendente por fila pero que respete los nombres de las columnas para mostrar primero la columna con el valor más alto en el primer mes, y así sucesivamente con todas las lineas de mes. ya se que la primera prevalece.
Es lo que se hace de forma manual eligiendo la opcion ordenar de izquierda a derecha y ordenando por filas en excel.

Este código (que no es mío) lo hace pero ignora totalmente las columnas, sólo atiende a las lineas y mezcla los datos de todas las columnas. Alguien puede ayudarme por favor? Gracias de antemano.

Preferiría en vba excel pero si alguien sabe hacerlo en sas también me vale. Gracias

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+S
'
    Range("d2:g2").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("d2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=c1 _
        , OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    Range("d3:g3").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("d3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=c1 _
        , OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        Range("d4:g4").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("d4"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=c1 _
        , OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La macro que estás utilizando parece haberse generado automáticamente, ésto es debido a que los rangos que utilizas no se corresponden con los de la tabla donde pone Range("d2:g2").Select, sustituyelo por A2:K13 o bien por el rango que quieras ordenar.

Esto es,  Range("d2:g2").Select por Range("A2:K13").Select o bien toca grabar una nueva macro o codificar una correctamente a mano.